# Remove filter depending of received parameter value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT AVG( [ DC ]. [ ContractedAmount ]) AS [AverageContractedAmount]
    , MAX([DC].[ContractedAmount]) AS [MaxContractedAmount]
    , MIN([DC].[ContractedAmount]) AS [MinContractedAmount]
    FROM [DesignCustomer] AS [DC]
    INNER JOIN [Design] AS [D] ON [DC].[DesignKey] = [D].[DesignKey]
    INNER JOIN [Task] AS [T] ON [D].[DesignKey] = [t].[DesignKey]
    INNER JOIN [ProjectDesign] AS [PD] ON [D].[DesignKey] = [PD].[DesignKey]
    INNER JOIN [Project] AS [P] ON [PD].[ProjectKey] = [P].[ProjectKey]
    INNER JOIN [Address] AS [A] ON [A].[AddressGuid] = [P].[ProjectGuid]
    WHERE [DC].[ContractedAmount] != 0.00
    AND [D].StatusKey = 66
    AND (@MinWoodStories IS NULL OR [P].[WoodStories] BETWEEN @MinWoodStories AND @MaxWoodStories)
    AND (@MinNumberOfUnits IS NULL OR [P].[NumberOfUnits] BETWEEN @MinNumberOfUnits AND @MaxNumberOfUnits)
    AND (@MinSqrFootage IS NULL OR [P].[SquareFootage] BETWEEN @MinSqrFootage AND @MaxSqrFootage)
    AND (@MinNumberOfSegs IS NULL OR [P].[Bldg_Segs] BETWEEN @MinNumberOfSegs AND @MaxNumberOfSegs)
    AND ([DC].[CustomerKey] = @CustomerKey
    OR [A].[RegionKey] = @RegionKey
    OR [A].[StateKey] = @StateKey)
```

As you can see in my last `AND` clause I have "RegionKey = @RegionKey"

```
 AND ([DC].[CustomerKey] = @CustomerKey
                      OR [A].[RegionKey] = @RegionKey
                      OR [A].[StateKey] = @StateKey)
```

In some cases I can receive @RegionKey = 0 which does not exist as a register on my database. Case 0 in my code means "All", so I want to know how can I modify this query in order if I receive 0 in @RegioKey parameter just remove regionKey  filter. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Aside: You might want to read up on [catch-all queries](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2018/03/13/revisiting-catch-all-queries/). And using `NULL` to indicate an unknown is generally preferable to picking a _magic number_ that could "never" occur in the real data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
AND ([DC].[CustomerKey] = @CustomerKey
                      OR [A].[RegionKey] = @RegionKey OR @RegionKey = 0
                      OR [A].[StateKey] = @StateKey)
```